# IntoIterator returning proxy type that'll return indices during iteration in Rust

Tags: rust

**TL;DR:** Is there some way to provide implementation for both mutable and immutable variant at once?

I'm just beginning to learn Rust, and first thing I wanted to do is use `IntoIterator` for a proxy class that'd keep track of 2D `x` and `y` indices, with underlying structure being linear `Vec<f32>`.
Something like that:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Array {
    inner: Vec<f32>,
    width: usize,
}

pub struct ArrayItem<'a> {
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
    pub element: &'a f32 // value
}

pub struct TwoDimIter<T>
where 
    T: Iterator
{
    cur_x: usize,
    cur_y: usize,
    width: usize,
    inner_iter: T // Iterator to underlying Vec<f32>
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for TwoDimIter<T>
where T: Iterator<Item = &'a f32>
{
    type Item = ArrayItem<'a>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> std::option::Option<<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item> {
        let op_value = self.inner_iter.next();
        if op_value.is_some() {
            self.cur_x += 1;
            self.cur_y += self.cur_x / self.width; // usually 0
            self.cur_x %= self.width; // usually the same as was before

            Some(ArrayItem{ x: self.cur_x, y: self.cur_y, element: op_value.unwrap() })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

So usage would look like:

```
pub fn gauss_seidel(output: &mut Array, input: &Array, weight: f32) {
    for val in input {
        let (x, y, &value) = (val.x, val.y, val.element);
    }
}
```

I was mostly following implementation of `Vec` itself and I ended up with a lot of code, because I had to duplicate every struct I introduced for Mutable variant (if passed as `&mut Array`).
I am used to C++ templates and I wanted to somehow merge implementations for mutable and immutable variant (based on return type of a function for example - like SFINAE does), but I failed - I have no idea how to do it.

Is there some way to provide implementation for both mutable and immutable variant at once?

Full code I've got:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Array {
    inner: Vec<f32>,
    width: usize,
}

impl Array {
    pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize) -> Array {
        Array { inner: vec![0.; width * height], width }
    }

    pub fn get(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&f32> {
        self.inner.get(y * self.width + x)
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&mut f32> {
        self.inner.get_mut(y * self.width + x)
    }
}

pub struct ArrayItem<'a> {
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
    pub element: &'a f32
}

pub struct MutArrayItem<'a> {
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
    pub element: &'a mut f32
}

pub struct TwoDimIter<T>
where 
    T: Iterator
{
    cur_x: usize,
    cur_y: usize,
    width: usize,
    inner_iter: T
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for TwoDimIter<T>
where T: Iterator<Item = &'a f32>
{
    type Item = ArrayItem<'a>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> std::option::Option<<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item> {
        let op_value = self.inner_iter.next();
        if op_value.is_some() {
            self.cur_x += 1;
            self.cur_y += self.cur_x / self.width; // usually 0
            self.cur_x %= self.width; // usually the same as was before

            Some(ArrayItem{ x: self.cur_x, y: self.cur_y, element: op_value.unwrap() })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

pub struct MutTwoDimIter<T>
where
    T: Iterator
{
    cur_x: usize,
    cur_y: usize,
    width: usize,
    inner_iter: T
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for MutTwoDimIter<T>
where T: Iterator<Item = &'a mut f32>
{
    type Item = MutArrayItem<'a>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> std::option::Option<<Self as std::iter::Iterator>::Item> {
        let op_value = self.inner_iter.next();
        if op_value.is_some() {
            self.cur_x += 1;
            self.cur_y += self.cur_x / self.width; // usually 0
            self.cur_x %= self.width; // usually the same as was before

            Some(MutArrayItem{ x: self.cur_x, y: self.cur_y, element: op_value.unwrap() })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

use core::slice::{self};

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Array {
    type Item = ArrayItem<'a>;
    type IntoIter = TwoDimIter<slice::Iter<'a, f32>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> <Self as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter { 
        TwoDimIter{ cur_x: 0, cur_y: 0, width: self.width, inner_iter: self.inner.iter() }
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut Array {
    type Item = MutArrayItem<'a>;
    type IntoIter = MutTwoDimIter<slice::IterMut<'a, f32>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> <Self as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter { 
        MutTwoDimIter{ cur_x: 0, cur_y: 0, width: self.width, inner_iter: self.inner.iter_mut() }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there some way to provide implementation for both mutable and immutable variant at once?" std use macro https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#3212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close; you've just gotten a little too specific too soon. `TwoDimIter` is really a general-purpose iterator adapter; you could use it to wrap any kind of iterator, not just a `std::slice::Iter`. `TwoDimIter` is a lot like `std::iter::Enumerate`, actually, except that it counts funky. So let's take our cue from `Enumerate`.

```
pub struct Enumerate2D<I> {
    index: usize,
    width: usize,
    inner: I,
}

impl<I> Iterator for Enumerate2D<I>
where I: Iterator
{
    // I'll use tuples here instead of a custom ArrayItem struct but that would
    // work fine too if you want
    type Item = ((usize, usize), I::Item);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next().map(|item| {
            let (x, y) = (self.index % self.width, self.index / self.width);
            self.index += 1;
            ((x, y), item)
        })
    }
}
```

This is the only `Iterator` implementation that we need to write because it will work for any `Item`. If you like, you can write an extension trait that gives all `Iterator`s an `.enumerate_2d(width)` method to wrap it. But for now we'll just write the `IntoIterator` implementations for `&Array` and `&mut Array`:

```
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Array {
    type IntoIter = Enumerate2D<slice::Iter<'a, f32>>;
    type Item = <Self::IntoIter as Iterator>::Item;

    fn into_iter(self) -> <Self as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter { 
        Enumerate2D { index: 0, width: self.width, inner: self.inner.iter() }
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut Array {
    type IntoIter = Enumerate2D<slice::IterMut<'a, f32>>;
    type Item = <Self::IntoIter as Iterator>::Item;

    fn into_iter(self) -> <Self as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter { 
        Enumerate2D { index: 0, width: self.width, inner: self.inner.iter_mut() }
    }
}
```

We still need to write both, because there's not really any way to abstract over different reference types and different iterator types at the same time. You could write a macro, but it's kind of hard and for two implementations it's probably not worthwhile. You can also write one for `Array` if you want:

```
impl IntoIterator for Array {
    type IntoIter = Enumerate2D<std::vec::IntoIter<f32>>;
    type Item = <Self::IntoIter as Iterator>::Item;

    fn into_iter(self) -> <Self as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter { 
        Enumerate2D { index: 0, width: self.width, inner: self.inner.into_iter() }
    }
}
```

You use these a lot like you would use an `Enumerate`:

```
for ((x, y), value) in input {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I only added constraints for `I` to be `std::iter::Iterator`.